# Select output query with specific format using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I need, if possible, a T-SQL query that will return the values in a specific format from the columns.

I have two tables:

The first table is `PrimeClosureInformation` table

[This is dbo.PrimeClosureInformation table]

And the second table is `dbo.Event`:

I did join with two table to get All the data for them Where This condition

```
 dbo.Event ON dbo.Event.EntityID = dbo.PrimeClosureInformation.PrimeClosureInformationPK
```

but it returns the result like this:

[Here is the result i want to get it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1Emr.png)

The format I need it for every `PrimeClosureInformationPK` record all events comments in one record or in one line like this example

`PrimeClosureInformationPK`  `Invoiced Remarks`  `EventCommentFirst`  `EventCreationDateTimeFirst`  `EventCommentSecond`  `EventCreationDateTimeSecond`

And so on

This is the join I did it with the image for the result
[this is the result of join i was did](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIArP.png)

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
    dbo.PrimeClosureInformation.PrimeClosureInformationPK,
    dbo.PrimeClosureInformation.Invoiced,
    dbo.PrimeClosureInformation.Remarks,
    dbo.Event.EventComment,
    dbo.Event.EventCreationDateTime,
FROM
    dbo.PrimeClosureInformation
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Event ON dbo.Event.EntityID = dbo.PrimeClosureInformation.PrimeClosureInformationPK
```

Comment: Hey, you're **really** hurting yourself by posting images of your tables instead of text. For several reasons, lots of people who might have helped just won't even see the question.

Comment: Also... best practice for this situation is for your client code or reporting tool to roll up and group the results into a single record per Closure PK, rather than trying to do it in SQL.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn thanks for advice , i want to do it in SQL

Answer (score 0):

if I understand it correclty all values of one PK should be display in one column, than you can try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(dbo.PrimeClosureInformation.PrimeClosureInformationPK, '|' , dbo.PrimeClosureInformation.Invoiced, '', dbo.PrimeClosureInformation.Remarks, '|'
    dbo.Event.EventComment, '|'
    dbo.Event.EventCreationDateTime
FROM
    dbo.PrimeClosureInformation
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Event ON dbo.Event.EntityID = dbo.PrimeClosureInformation.PrimeClosureInformationPK
```

Comment: I had updated the question with image of  the result i wan to get it

Comment: This can be done with a subquery i think. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/subqueries?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: how i can do it can you write the Query

Comment: I tested it with subquery, but this is not working as you expected. A better way to find a solution is to do it in the code for the visualization.